# Capistrano Deploy Timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

Alright, so, I've looked around on the web and it doesn't really look like a lot of other people have this issue, but maybe something else is wrong with what we're doing.

I've mananged to distill it down to what I think is a useful test case:

config/deploy.rb:

```
## Excerpt
task :big_delay, :roles => :web do
  run "sleep 480"
  run "echo Meow Meow Meow"
end
```

And stupid_script.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh foo 'sleep 480; echo Meow Meow Meow'
```

Where foo is the name of the same server we deploy to.

When I run both of these it should connect to the other box, do nothing for 8 minutes, then spit out some useless text and complete.

The stupid_script works, and the cap task fails.
I see the remote command finish with ps xf, but cap doesn't seem to notice anymore.
If the sleep is 20 instead of 240, the cap task works fine.

Obviously this task is super useless, but we do have expensive things run on deploy that trigger this, and I've made this to rule out any blame on ssh.

Another data point, if we ssh into the box and put the code there and then run cap deploy from there, then it works fine.

So... there seems to be some weird interplay going on between ssh and capistrano.
Thoughts?

Comment: Not entering this as an answer because I'm not sure it'll fix your issue, but the ssh connection could be timing out. Try setting ClientAliveInterval and ClientAliveCountMax in the server's /etc/ssh/sshd_config: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/open-ssh-server-connection-drops-out-after-few-or-n-minutes-of-inactivity.html

Comment: You can try and twiddle your keepalive settings or make your stall script print out something intermittently. This could be a spinny waiting wheel, a series of dots, or even just carriage returns to twig the connection.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I felt that I excluded the ssh timeout thing with ./stupid_script.sh, which sshs into the same box and runs the same commands and never fails.

Comment: Having the cap deploy:big_delay task spit some output out every second does appear to work, which is an interesting datapoint, but the task it's serving as an analog for doesn't have output.

Comment: stupid_script.sh uses your command line ssh client, capistrano uses net-ssh. You may have keep-alive settings configured in /etc/ssh_config or .ssh/ssh_config that keep the connection open when you run the regular ssh client, but not capistrano.

Comment: The timeout theory also explains why the deploy works locally, but not remotely. You could test this out by opening up a Net::SSH session in irb, and running "sleep 480 && echo hello" (see http://pastebin.com/rmKWeqmi). Does it return?

Comment: @choover I get `undefined method `new' for Net::SSH:Module` when I try the code from that pastebin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set ClientAliveInterval and ClientAliveCountMax in /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the server as choover suggests. I had the exact same issue with "assets:precompile" on my deploy until I made that change.

Comment: I had the same issue with precompiling assets, and this solved it for me.

Comment: It seems kind of ridiculous to me that capistrano ignores all local ssh config... Anyway, it seems that improves things.

Comment: Note that changing the value of ClientAliveCountMax is not necessary. It's default values of 3 is enough in most cases.

Comment: I found this useful https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/what-options-serveraliveinterval-and-clientaliveinterval-in-sshd-config-exac